# How to deploy an artifact from group of artifacts to jfrog artifactory using jenkins post build action

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-mission-control

My maven group project hierarchy like

```
maven_group_project

 - sub_module_1
 - sub_module_2
 - sub_module_3
```

When I run maven command `clean package install` on `maven_group_project` then it gives `sub_module_1.jar`,  `sub_module_2.jar` and `sub_module_3.jar`.

I want to send only one(`sub_module_1.jar`) in artifactory (jFrog).

I use this plugin for sending artifact https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin

How I set the pattern to send only one artifact or any other way to send artifact.

> Note: This is a maven build project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done through the `Post Build Action -> Deploy artifacts to Artifactory` and use the `include patterns` with `*sub_module_1*`. It filters from all created jar and sends to artifactory server.

[image]